# How to $poweroff BusyBox from windows machine

Tags: linux, networking, windows, busybox

I have an old windows xp pc and a Linux 2.6.15.7-ElinOS-453 i686
with BusyBox v1.6.1. I want to shutdown the windows xp computer from the Linux computer at the same time, and viceversa. (They are both connected through a LAN cable)

Would any one be able to tell how this work? I am trying to use the same Linux machine with windows 7 but unfortunately I do not have any information about the original XP creation so don`t know where to start.

Comment: excuse me, but I don't know what do you want to do...

Comment: I would like to know how i can power off the linux from windows embeded standard XP, or, how can i power off the windows embeded standards xp from the this linux

Comment: so: you want to shut down the two machines together, regardless of which one you are attending to; correct?

Comment: Thats correct. in majority of situations the windows computer is the one i`m working on. The linux normally sits without monitor or keyboard, so it`s important for me to "shutdown" linux automatically when the windows pc is being shutdown.